# why can't I use my whole 1TB HDD when I enabled Intel RST

Tags: storage, intel-rst

I'm have a few problems here. I have 1TB HDD and a 256GB SSD and I want to use Intel RST on them, but right from the BIOS before I apply changes I can only use 477GB of capacity. I want to use my SSD as a cache for my HDD using Intel RST. Am I missing something here or is this what using RAID drives really is?

Answer (score -1):

Using RST if you have a larger (minimum 64GB, but realistically at least 128GB)SSD is not going to buy you any performance boost.  Your best bet is to use the SSD as your boot device and the HDD for storage.  If you want to run a RAID it would be primarily to safeguard data, like running the HDD in RAID 1.  There are many ways to set up a RAID array so researching it first would be a good idea.  Intel RST is all done through software, called a 'soft RAID'.  The reason you were seeing 477GB is you were likely setting it up to mirror data on two 500GB partitions on your HDD.
If I were setting up a machine with this hardware I would use the SSD as BOOT, the HDD as storage and possibly backup for the boot drive.  I would also back up the HDD and the SSD to some type of external media.  This would give you the best possible mix of speed, performance, and security.